# How do I find the constant in the formula Unbiased Estimators of Variance and Mean that takes on a new form different from textbooks?

Tags: statistics

Let X1, . . . , Xn be n i.i.d. random variables, where each Xi has an unknown mean
E[Xi] = µ and unknown variance Var(X) = σ^2  Let Xn and Sn^2 denote the sample mean and
the unbiased sample variance, respectively, of {X1, . . . , Xn}.

[Questions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDoVq.png)

I am confused over (i) where they put the summation as n-1 so I am having difficulties relating that to the original formula of unbiased estimate of σ^2 in textbooks. I would also appreciate some hints given for part (ii) as I have been stuck here for quite sometime.

I am also unable to format the summation signs in the post, thus had to insert an image, sorry about that in advance.

Comment: First, what is your understanding of "unbiased estimator"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$E\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (X_{i+1} - X_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} E[(X_{i+1} - X_i)^2]$$
Note that $X_{i+1} - X_i$ has mean zero and variance $2 \sigma^2$, so
$$E[(X_{i+1} - X_i)^2] = \text{Var}(X_{i+1} - X_i) + (E[X_{i+1} - X_i])^2 = 2\sigma^2.$$
Now can you find what value of $c_1$ will yield $E[c_1 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (X_{i+1} - X_i)^2 ] = \sigma^2$?

---

You know $E s_n^2 = \sigma^2$. Also, we know $\overline{X}_n$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$, so $E[\overline{X}_n^2] = \text{Var}(\overline{X}_n^2) + (E[\overline{X}_n])^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$. Now can you find what value of $c_2$ will yield $E[\overline{X}_n^2 - c_2 s_n^2] = \mu^2$?